# Swagger 3.0.1 and oAuth1

Tags: swagger, oauth-1.0a

Currently, there is no oAuth1 support in [OpenApi 3.0.1 specifications](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#security-scheme-object)
I need to indicate that some endpoints require an oAuth1.
May someone has some ideas, insights how to do it?
I'm not expecting to have a full swagger functionality,
Just a visualisation that this endpoint is secured or not secured.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: My goal is to indicate that some endpoints in my API are secured by oAuth1.
Officially 3rd version doesn't support oAuth1
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/
Through this question, I want to know, may somebody already investigated this and have a solution or a workaround for this.